# Regex with delimiters

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with the regex commands:

```
text="blue:
allocatable
allocate
assign" //it has delimiters (new lines)

String patternblue = ".*blue.*";
boolean isMatchblue = Pattern.matches(patternblue, text.toString());
System.out.println(isMatchblue);
```

gives "false", what happens?

I checked the other posts in the forum but I don't get it working neither with .*? nor ?s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific `Pattern`, you need to use the `DOTALL` flag, as the `.*` after `blue` will not match a newline otherwise.

Since there is no `matches` override that takes optional flags, you might end up changing your code to:

```
Pattern.compile(patternblue, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(text).matches();
```